# Hybrid semaphore/cyclic barrier needed

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, cyclicbarrier

I'm working on a staged job system, which currently works as follows (pseudocode):

```
cyclicbarrier.init(numthreads)
on each thread:
  for each stage s:
    loop forever:
      pop job from joblist[s]
      if no job:
        break
      execute job
    wait at cyclicbarrier
```

This causes all jobs in the stage to finish executing before moving onto the next stage.

`cyclicbarrier` is implemented using two semaphores:

```
sem1(0)
sem2(0)
n = 0

function wait:
  if atomic_incr(n) == maxthreads:
    sem1.signal(maxthreads)
  sem1.wait()

  if atomic_decr(n) == 0:
    sem2.signal(maxthreads)
  sem2.wait()
```

I would like to add support for a job to be able to add 1 or more jobs into the currently running stage, and have those jobs also execute before the stage continues. The above code will do this, however if this job is added after a thread has reached the barrier, then it will be executed sub-optimally, as a waiting thread could be executing it but isn't.

I've boiled down the problem to needing a kind of hybrid `semaphore`/`cyclicbarrier`, which for convenience I'll call a `sembarrier`. Here's how it would function:

```
function wait:
  n--
  if n < 0 and n > -maxthreads:
    suspend until signaled
  else if n <= -maxthreads:
    signal(maxthreads)
```

Essentially, this `sembarrier` works just like a `semaphore`, but when enough threads are waiting on it, it behaves like a `cyclicbarrier` and releases them all.

So, here's the new implementation using the `sembarrier`.

`sembarrier` constructor looks like:

```
sembarrier(initial_value, num_threads)
```

Create a `sembarrier` for each stage:

```
n = num_theads
for each stage s:
  sembarrier[s].init(0, n)
```

This would be the modified loop, using the `sembarrier` array:

```
on each thread:
  for each stage s:
    loop forever:
      sembarrier[s].wait()
      pop job from joblist[s]
      if no job:
        break;
      execute job
```

Additionally, when adding to `joblist`:

```
function AddJob(stage s, job j):
  joblist[s].push(j)
  sembarrier[s].signal()
```

Questions:

1) How can I efficiently implement `sembarrier`? I have access to basic concurrency structures, such as mutexes and semaphores. I also have the standard atomic ops.

2) Is there an alternative solution to my original problem?

Thanks!